# Strange delimiters when copy-pasting out of Excel sheet

Tags: r, excel, shiny

I've been working on an R Shiny app which allows you to paste in datasets as text, then separates them out into data frames and highlights the differences between them. Generally, it works well, but I recently ran into an issue where for two datasets which appear the same all cells are inexplicably highlighted.

When I tried pasting them directly into RStudio, rather than the Shiny app, I found the difference. One of them looked normal:

[image]

However, the other had strange delimiters:

[image: Second dataset]

Both came from the same sheet of the same Excel file, displayed side-by-side. What are they? When I try to paste them elsewhere, they disappear, or just appear as tabs as I would expect. But obviously R considers them different somehow. How can I fix this?

In case it's helpful, I'll add my code for the actual app here. It's split into two parts: first, the external functions that get used within the app, and then the Shiny app code.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Helper functions--------------------------------------------------------------

# Generates divisors for text_to_data_rstudio
divisors <- function(num){
  divs <- c()
  for (i in 2:(num/2)){
    if (num%%i == 0) divs <- append(divs, i)
  }
  return(divs)
}

# Converts text input from RStudio viewer to data frame
text_to_data_rstudio <- function(text){
  # Maybe add something here to remove the last character if it is a new line character
  lines <- strsplit(text, '\n')[[1]]
  sep <- NA
  for (i in divisors(length(lines))){
    index <- 1 + i
    use <- TRUE
    for (j in 2:(length(lines)/i)){
      val2 <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(lines[index]))
      val1 <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(lines[index - i]))
      if(is.na(val2) | is.na(val1)){
        use <- FALSE
        break
      }
      if(val2 != val1 + 1){
        use <- FALSE
        break
      }
      index <- index + i
    }
    if(use){
      sep <- i
      break
    }
  }
  
  if(is.na(sep)){
    outdf <- data.frame('V1' = 'Couldn\'t', 'V2' = 'parse', 'V3' = 'data')
    return(outdf)
  }
  
  colslist <- list()
  for (i in 0:(length(lines)/sep - 1)){
    colslist[[i+1]] <- lines[(sep*i + 1):(sep*(i+1))]
  }
  outdf <- as.data.frame(rbind(colslist[[1]]))
  for (i in 2:length(colslist)) outdf <- rbind(outdf, colslist[[i]])
  
  return(outdf)
}

# Converts text input to data frame
text_to_data <- function(text, rowsep, cellsep){
  if(rowsep == 'New line' & cellsep == 'New line') return(text_to_data_rstudio(text))
  rowsep <- ifelse(rowsep == 'New line', '\n', '\t')
  cellsep <- ifelse(cellsep == 'Tab', '\t', '\n')
  rows <- strsplit(text, split = rowsep)[[1]]
  rowslist <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(rows)){
    rowslist[[i]] <- strsplit(rows[i], split = cellsep)[[1]]
  }
  width <- max(sapply(rowslist, length))
  if(length(rowslist[[1]]) < width) rowslist[[1]] <- c(rowslist[[1]], rep(NA, width - length(rowslist[[1]])))
  output <- rowslist[[1]]
  for (i in 2:length(rowslist)){
    if(length(rowslist[[i]]) < width) rowslist[[i]] <- c(rowslist[[i]], rep(NA, width - length(rowslist[[i]])))
    output <- rbind(output, rowslist[[i]])
  }
  return(as.data.frame(output))
}

# Adds empty rows/columns to each data frame as necessary to make them the same size
df_expand <- function(x, y){
  rep_col <- function(df, times){
    for (i in 1:times) df <- cbind(df, rep(NA, nrow(df)))
    return(df)
  }
  rep_row <- function(df, times){
    for (i in 1:times) df <- rbind(df, rep(NA, ncol(df)))
    return(df)
  }
  
  if(ncol(x) > ncol(y)) y <- rep_col(y, ncol(x)-ncol(y))
  if(ncol(y) > ncol(x)) x <- rep_col(x, ncol(y)-ncol(x))
  if(nrow(x) > nrow(y)) y <- rep_row(y, nrow(x)-nrow(y))
  if(nrow(y) > nrow(x)) x <- rep_row(x, nrow(y)-nrow(x))
  
  colnames(x) <- paste('V', 1:length(x), sep = '')
  colnames(y) <- paste('V', 1:length(y), sep = '')
  
  return(list(x, y))
}

# Function to identify differences between two data frames
df_diff <- function(x, y){
  dflist <- df_expand(x, y)
  x <- dflist[[1]]
  y <- dflist[[2]]
  
  diffs <- list()
  for (i in 1:ncol(x)){
    for (j in 1:nrow(x)){
      if(!is.na(x[j, i]) & !is.na(y[j, i]) & x[j, i] != y[j, i]) diffs[[length(diffs)+1]] <- c(j, i)
      if((!is.na(x[j, i]) & is.na(y[j, i])) | (is.na(x[j, i]) & !is.na(y[j, i]))) diffs[[length(diffs)+1]] <- c(j, i)
    }
  }
  
  return(diffs)
}

# Extracts row indices from output of df_diff
df_diff_rows <- function(diffs){
  if(length(diffs) > 0){
    rows <- c()
    for (i in 1:length(diffs)) rows <- append(rows, diffs[[i]][1])
    return(rows)
  }
  return(NULL)
}

# Extracts column indices from output of df_diff
df_diff_cols <- function(diffs){
  if(length(diffs) > 0){
    cols <- c()
    for (i in 1:length(diffs)) cols <- append(cols, diffs[[i]][2])
    return(cols)
  }
  return(NULL)
}

# Changes color of cells with specified indices
changeCellsColor <- function(rows, cols){
  stopifnot(length(rows) == length(cols))
  c(
    "function(row, data, num, index){",
    sprintf("  var rows = [%s];", paste0(rows-1, collapse = ",")),
    sprintf("  var cols = [%s];", paste0(cols, collapse = ",")),
    "  for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i){",
    "    if(index == rows[i]){",
    "      $('td:eq(' + cols[i] + ')', row)",
    "        .css({'background-color': 'orange'});",
    "    }",
    "  }",
    "}"
  )
}


# App code----------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Data Comparer'),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(6,
           textAreaInput('data1', 'Enter first dataset here:', rows = 5, value = 'No\tdata\tyet\nNo\tdata\tyet\nNo\tdata\tyet'),
           selectInput('rowsep1', 'Enter row delimiter:', c('New line', 'Tab')),
           selectInput('cellsep1', 'Enter cell delimiter:', c('Tab', 'New line')),
           dataTableOutput('dftable1'),
    ),
    
    column(6,
           textAreaInput('data2', 'Enter second dataset here:', rows = 5, value = 'No\tdata\tyet\nNo\tdata\tyet\nNo\tdata\tyet'),
           selectInput('rowsep2', 'Enter row delimiter:', c('New line', 'Tab')),
           selectInput('cellsep2', 'Enter cell delimiter:', c('Tab', 'New line')),
           dataTableOutput('dftable2')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data1 <- reactive(text_to_data(input$data1, input$rowsep1, input$cellsep1))
  data2 <- reactive(text_to_data(input$data2, input$rowsep2, input$cellsep2))
  diffs_rows <- reactive(df_diff_rows(df_diff(data1(), data2())))
  diffs_cols <- reactive(df_diff_cols(df_diff(data1(), data2())))
  data_exp <- reactive(df_expand(data1(), data2()))
  output$dftable1 <- renderDataTable(datatable(data_exp()[[1]], rownames = FALSE,
                                           options = list(
                                             'pageLength' = 25,
                                             # dom = 't',
                                             rowCallback = JS(changeCellsColor(diffs_rows(), diffs_cols()-1))
                                           )))
  output$dftable2 <- renderDataTable(datatable(data_exp()[[2]], rownames = FALSE,
                                           options = list(
                                             'pageLength' = 25,
                                             # dom = 't',
                                             rowCallback = JS(changeCellsColor(diffs_rows(), diffs_cols()-1))
                                           )))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note: I was able to make the app work by adding the following line to the beginning of the text_to_data function (included as an image because it doesn't display properly in Stack Overflow's code chunks):

[image: Code fix]

However, I still don't understand what this symbol is or why it's appearing. If anybody can explain that I would greatly appreciate it.

Note 2: It seems that even though the character doesn't display on Stack Overflow, it is still contained in the text somehow. So if you want to see it for yourself, try pasting the following string into RStudio: '4​ 4​​9​'.

Comment: what is the advantage of pasting in datasets compared to using a file reader?

Comment: The idea is that the user can directly import from a variety of sources, i.e. if they come across a table in a power point or a word document, then they can simply copy and paste it into this app rather than having to create an Excel document and then read that in. I wanted to make the process quicker and easier by eliminating a step. To that end, it supports multiple types of row/column delimiters to make it more versatile.

Comment: yea I am not too sure how to handle this problem. I think if you are copying and pasting from various sources you will eventually end up with weird delimiters. You might need to further add  in code after the paste to try and remove all delimiters and turn them into whatever makes the app work. For further help it would be great to see the app and code.

Comment: That makes sense, I was just surprised that I got two different delimiter styles from Excel. I added my code for the app above if it's helpful.

Comment: you might also be interested in https://github.com/MilesMcBain/datapasta which offers similar features for copy / pasting data to / from R

Comment: these are unicode - ZERO WIDTH SPACE (U+200B)